# simple way to include node_modules in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

How do you include /node_modules in a laravel 5.5 application, i referenced this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix

i can do this

```
npm install angular-moment moment --save
```

and it will make a /node_modules directory, however laravel ignores it

lets say i want to do this

```
<script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

it will not work, it will show an error

i currently have this in my webpack, what will be the best way to integrate it ?

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just include it in your app.js so it is complied in...

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

Then access it as moment... like

```
moment().format();
```

Comment: Yeah, and just make sure in your main php file where you are putting your compiled scripts you use something like `src="{{mix('build/app.js')}}"` in the script to access it properly.

Comment: hmmm let me try it out

Comment: @serge then do i still do this `<script src="{{url('node_modules/moment/moment.js')}}"></script>`

Comment: Seems like assigning to the variable is a MUST, if I just required my node module `require('MyModule')`, it didn't work - when I assigned it to the variable which I was expecting  -  `MyModule = require('MyModule');`  - this worked